# Magento : 2 “Argument passed must be an instance of Customeractivation”

Tags: magento2

I have one module, as "Customeractivation".

In "customeractivation" Observer file, I want to call some methods of helper class of "customeractivation" module.
But when i injected dependencies to construct method i am getting following error.
Argument passed must be an instance of Customeractivation”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove an old generated files using rm -rf var/generation/* command in magento versions less than 2.2 and use rm -rf generated/* for the Magento greater than 2.2 from the magento root directory.